# Pull all numbers in any given array and then add them all together.

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, integer

I am trying to come up with a function that can take any type of array (with objects, other arrays, strings, numbers, booleans, etc) and pull out all of the numbers (even if they are strings) and then add them all together return the total sum.

So far I was trying to come up with a function that would find all the integers first and add them all together before worrying about converting any strings representing numbers into integers and adding those too:

```
function arraySum(array) {
  // the array could be containing integers, strings, objects and/or arrays like itself.
  // Sum all the integers you find, anywhere in the nest of arrays.
  var sum = 0
  var numArray = []

    for (i=0; i > array.length; i++) {
        if (typeOf array[i] == Number) {
            numArray.push(i);
            for (j=0; j> numArray.length; j++) {
                sum += numArray[j];
                return sum;
            };
        }
    }
}

arraySum([1,2,3,["Here is a string", "67", 67], {key: "55", value: 55}, true, 56]);
```

I was expecting the return value of sum to be 184

The sum should return 306 (once function is updated to convert number strings into integers)

Comment: Why would someone do this?

Comment: It's a level on this game at : http://games.usvsth3m.com/javascript-under-pressure/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, ["Here is a string", "67", 67], {key: "55", value: 55 }, true, 56];


function arraySum(obj) {
    var sum = 0;
    var num = Number(obj);

    if (typeof obj === 'boolean') {
        return 0;
    }

    if (typeof num === 'number' && !isNaN(num)) {
        return num;
    }

    if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return 0;
    }

    if (obj.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            sum += arraySum(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var p in obj) {
            sum += arraySum(obj[p]);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}


console.log(arraySum(a));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Vidul

Comment: @xgrioux My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in jq 1.5 (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).  As a jq program, it will accept arbitrary JSON input.  Since your input is not strictly JSON, the following shows a method for handling the input you proposed:

```
# summation_walk scans for numbers or numeric strings
# everywhere except in the key names, and adds them up:
def summation_walk:
  walk( if type == "object" then .[] else . end )
  | walk( if type == "string" then tonumber?
          elif (type | . == "boolean" or . == "null") then empty
          else .
          end )
  | flatten
  | add;

[1,2,3,["Here is a string", "67", 67], {key: "55", value: 55}, true, 56]
| summation_walk
```

yields:

```
306
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping inside of a loop. The first loop needs to find all the numbers, then you can loop and add the numbers populated in this secondary array:

Edit: fixed many errors in your code, it's working here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b442b3pb/)

```
function arraySum(arr) {

    var sum=0, numArray=[]; // <==== correct initialisation

    // first, find numbers
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof(arr[i]) === 'number') numArray.push(arr[i]);
    }

    // now we can add numbers
    for (var j=0; j<numArray.length; j++) {
        sum += numArray[j];
    }

    return sum; // <====== put return here [1, 2, 3, 56]
}

var sum = arraySum([1,2,3,["Here is a string", "67", 67], {key: "55", value: 55}, true, 56]);

console.log(sum); // 62
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... when I run the function I get this message =  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" it is getting caught up in "typeOf array[i]" ...

Comment: I am playing a game at http://games.usvsth3m.com/javascript-under-pressure/..... and it's the final challenge and responds with ....Testing "arraySum([[1,2,3],4,5])"...
WRONG: Got 9 but expected 15. Try again!